# Bash select with string return

Tags: mysql, select, command-line

I'm executing the following query, to update the data in my database:

```
mysql -u root -ppassword -e "UPDATE table SET data = 1 WHERE id = 5"
```

Is there a way to execute the same query, but with the `SELECT` statement ? Of course there is, but how can I fetch the returned value then? Is that even possible?

Comment: You will have to do a better job of explaining what you are after. What do you want to select? Do you want to update the table with values from another select?

Comment: @nnichols No, don't look at the update one. All I need is something like: `mysql -u root -ppassword -e "SELECT something from mytable where id = 1 LIMIT 1"` (there will always be a limit 1), but how can I fetch returned value (`something`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql -u root -ppassword -e "UPDATE table SET data = 1 WHERE id = 5; SELECT data FROM table WHERE id = 5"
```

Comment: Fine, but HOW can I fetch the "data" returned by SELECT?

Comment: @Cyclone, what do you mean by "I can fetch"? What are you going to do having fetched?

Comment: Normally, mysql command line will return something like this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=x7zu5jcH , I want it to return signle `Hello` (return value). +1 for nw :)

Comment: @Cyclone, I currently do not have a mysql at hand, but I do know that the format of the output can be controlled by various options. For example, `-X` will output the data as XML, and there are options to skip table headers.

Comment: I've looked at man mysql, and found the `-s` parameter, which cut all of the `+-+-+-+-` string, but there are now 2 lines: Field Name and below the field value is shown, it all I need is to cut the first line of returned string in bash :P I guess there is a function for this !

Comment: Ok, fixed - I've used `awk` to cut the line! Thank you :)